# Typescript Bluebird definition

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, bluebird

I am trying to convert a NodeJS project to Typescript.
I have used a lot the [Bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird) library for promises, so I wanted to give a try to its type definition.
I see a lot of errors like these in the definition file.

[image: screenshot]

Is it because of something wrong in my configuration?
This is my tsconfig.json.

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
  "target": "ES6",
  "removeComments": true,
  "preserveConstEnums": true,
  "out": "/dist/server/server.js",
  "sourceMap": true
},
"exclude": [
    "node_modules"
]
}
```

Answer (score -4, accepted):

You are targeting ES6. ES6 already has Promises, so using Bluebird with it is redundant and is causing those errors. Using `"target": "ES5"` will get rid of those errors. If you're using VS Code, you may need to restart it to catch the changes. On another note, you should add `"module": "commonjs"` to configuration as well :).

Comment: Thank you. So I will try to use ES6 promises without Bluebird. Thanks!

Comment: There are at least 100 reasons to use Bluebird, even in ES6.  The ES6 promises are a tiny subset of what Bluebird offers and Bluebird is entirely compatible with ES6.